# Xmonad - Spawn a program silently on specified monitor and workspace?

Tags: haskell, xmonad

How to start a program on specific monitor and specific workspace silently without focusing on it, sort of like you do when you press `Mod + Shift + n`? The problem with the following approach

```hs
className =? "ProgramClass" --> doShift ( workspaces !! n ),
```

is that it not only moves the window to the workspace it also opens a workspace, which I would rather avoid. `spawnOn` essentially does the same.

This is my current [config](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/asolopovas/dotfiles/fish/.config/xmonad/xmonad.hs)

Comment: Sorry, what does "opens a workspace" mean?

Comment: when application shift happens workspace becomes active, lets say I want the program to start 3rd workspace and  second screen while keeping workspace 1 and workspace 2  active on screen 1 and screen 2,

Comment: @DanielWagner I think they mean that the workspace steals focus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok my problem was `XMonad.Hooks.EwmhDesktops` after removing it from config `doShift` works without stealing my focus and moves items to a dedicated workspace without activating it.

Answer (score 0):

Too long comment here. I haven't tested the solution:

`doShift` doesn't change the workspace up to the documentation, the problem is that the new window is directly opened in the new workspace. I think you should define the `ManageHook` and execute it:

```
-- neccesary imports
import XMonad.ManageHook
import qualified XMonad.StackSet as W

-- creates a new ManageHook
openSilent :: WorkspaceId -> ManageHook
openSilent tows = do
   fromws <- liftX $ return . W.currentTag . windowset =<< get -- get the current ws tag
   wid    <- ask                                             -- get opened windowId
   doF $ W.view fromws . W.insertUp wid . W.view tows
--       |               |                |- move focus to "to" workspace
--       |               |- insert window
--       |- move focus back to "from" workspace
```

The hook should be use as regular

```
className =? "ProgramClass" --> openSilent "workspaceName"
```

Comment: xmonad.hs:320:33: error: Variable not in scope: w
    |
320 |    doF $ view fromws . insertUp w . view tows
    |                                 ^

Comment: xmonad.hs:320:33: error: Variable not in scope: w
    |
320 |    doF $ view fromws . insertUp w . view tows
    |                                 ^

Comment: xmonad.hs:320:10: error:
    • Variable not in scope: view :: t0 -> b0 -> WindowSet
    • Perhaps you meant ‘W.view’ (imported from XMonad.StackSet)
    |
320 |    doF $ view fromws . insertUp w . view tows
    |          ^^^^

Comment: xmonad.hs:318:31: error:
    • Variable not in scope: currentTag :: WindowSet -> t0
    • Perhaps you meant one of these:
        ‘W.currentTag’ (imported from XMonad.StackSet),
        ‘currentTime’ (imported from XMonad),
        ‘W.current’ (imported from XMonad.StackSet)
    |
318 |    fromws <- liftX $ return . currentTag . windowset =<< get -- get the current ws tag
    |                               ^^^^^^^^^^

Comment: @AndriusSolopovas sorry, I missed the qualified imports. Wrote the code without compiler available. Check the edit

Comment: it does open programs but they remain on the 1st display 1st workspace rather than on the 2n display and 7th workspace as I specify...

Comment: @AndriusSolopovas I don't have `Xmonad` installed, could you be more specific about what's happening? so the program opens in a wrong workspace? probably you can find functions in the `XMonad.StackSet` to achive what you want to do

Comment: Basically, I have two screen setup, both screens have an independent set of screens using `XMonad.Layout.IndependentScreens`. I have some chat apps such as WhatsApp, telegram, skype, which I want to open silently on `screen 2, workspace 1_7.`  While keeping `screen 1` with `workspace 0_1`, and `screen 2` with `workspace 1_1` active and empty on startup, and open chat apps in the background on `screen 2` and `workspaces 1_7`.  If I use `doShift` I get the following scenario. Xmonad opens all chat apps on `workspace 1_7` but this workspace appears on `screen 1` rather than `screen 2.

Comment: If I activate `workspace 0_1` on `screen 1` and then move focus to `screen 2`, the `workspace 1_7` becomes available  on the `screen 2` with all the chat apps. Which isn't end of the world its just that I have to do this every time I boot into xmonad which is extremely annoying.

Comment: @AndriusSolopovas in your `myStartupHook ` you have the following line `windows $ W.greedyView "1_7:chat"`. Up to the docs, this will move workspace `"1_7:chat"` to other currently focus screen. Maybe this has to do with your problem... Maybe not. Can you check to delete that line?

Comment: I have removed it but to no effect